# office pro plus 2016 privacy concern by organization

Tags: privacy, microsoft-office-2016

i am using office pro plus 2016 under a organization(my university), is that mean all the organization can access all my data while i am using office? thx

i had read below link and manage the privacy as stated, but i cant confirm if it is what as above stated.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/compat/manage-the-privacy-of-data-monitored-by-telemetry-in-office#disable-data-collection-for-the-agent

Comment: Have you asked your university's helpdesk?

Comment: yes, but they give official answer, but i want evident to prove my question, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your user role assignment(s) within the organization.  If you check your O365 for Business Plus' Admin portal (refer to [here](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-administration) and login, *or* access through the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.office365admin)), there should be a setting that shows which users have what access rights, with Global Administrators holding the highest visibility privileges.  You can also see what devices currently have your assigned license(s) deployed onto them, and even reset / force log-out (do this *before* securing your account with new password).

Note that while admins may not necessarily have direct access to your data, certain configurations may allow admins to reset your password, disable 2FA, etc., and gain access that way.

Comment: thx for the answer, and more detail on my inquiry, i use Word only not Onedrive. As u mentioned admin can access data through configurations, and i had installed in my personal computer, is that mean they have right to access all my personal data? thx :D